# Gitlab CI pipeline include: template doesn't work for a Python project

Tags: gitlab-ci

I've got a simple CI pipeline with the .gitlab-ci.yml file as below:

```
 include:
  template: SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

 variables:
  SAST_GOSEC_LEVEL: 2

 test:
   script:
   - apt-get update -qy
   - apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip
   - pip install -r requirements.txt
```

All actions in the script section works well, but the templated included was not picked up the build.

Thanks,
Paul

Answer (score 1):

This feature is available to only gold/ultimate accounts. Mine is a free one.

Answer (score 0):

[GitLab 15.6](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/11/22/gitlab-15-6-released/#more-accurate-sast-rules-for-python) (November 2022) seems to refers to this feature, but for *all* GitLab tiers.

> ### More accurate SAST rules for Python
>
> The GitLab Vulnerability Research team has updated the rules used for Python SAST scanning to catch more relevant problems with fewer false-positive results.
>
> The updated rules are included in the latest release of the Semgrep-based SAST analyzer.
> If you use the [default GitLab-managed CI/CD template for SAST](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Jobs/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml) on GitLab 15.0 or higher, your pipelines automatically update the Semgrep-based SAST analyzer to use the new rules.
>
> On your first scan after the update, existing findings we’ve identified as false positives will be marked [“No longer detected”](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/vulnerability_report/#activity-filter), and new findings may be created.
>
> See [Documentation](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/semgrep/-/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/376025).